# My Angular version-8 website is not generating sitemap

Tags: angular

I developed my website using the Angular framework, but i can't able to generate sitemap for website if i run my webite in xmlsite-map generator tool (online tool) it is not generating. please give me the solution to rectify this issue.

Comment: Are you using localhost by chance...? What's the website url, is it live and accessible?

Comment: yes i used local host but it is not generating sitemap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Server-side rendering (SSR) with Angular Universal

Here's an article that provides additional info about (SSR)

https://angular.io/guide/universal

For deployment follow this link

https://softtechdiary.com/how-to-deploy-angular-universal-to-production/

Answer (score 0):

If your website is hosted locally on your computer, the web can't see that your website is real, since it's only *locally* on your machine.

One way you could get around this problem is to push your app to a hosting service for free, like Heroku or Netlify, and then you will have a real URL that you can use for this sitemap generator.

Another option might be to use sitemap generator plugins in your website.

Here's an article that may provide additional options when creating a sitemap. https://www.ganatan.com/tutorials/search-engine-optimization-with-angular